# belongsToMany through using joinTable

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Using CakePhp 3.0.10

I want to create a `belongsTo` Relationship using the `through` options but I need to set the `joinTable` options too because my tables have a prefix

following the example in the book if I write:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Courses', [
    'through' => 'CourseMemberships',
    'joinTable' => 'prefix_course_memberships',

]);
```

I get the error:

```
1146 Table 'course_memberships' doesn't exist
```

Is that a bug or there is a way I can force cakephp to use my table?

Comment: course_memberships table exists??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `through` option supersedes the `joinTable` option, looking at the code, that's the expected behavior.

**[https://github.com/cakephp/.../src/ORM/Association/BelongsToMany.php#L173-L184](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.10/src/ORM/Association/BelongsToMany.php#L173-L184)**

So if you want to change the table name when using `through`, simply change it in the `CourseMembershipsTable` class like you would do it for any other table class

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->table('prefix_course_memberships');
    // ...
}
```